# How can I push to a native Postgres array using Rails commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Rather than using a serialized array, I have a native Postgres array. My migration file looks like -

```
class AddWhitelistedUsersToAccount < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :accounts, :whitelisted_users, :text, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

I have a serialized settings hash in my Account, but I do not have an array serializer. (I used to, but I've sinced dropped/rebuilt my db)

In my Rails console, `a = Account.first` returns an Account object,

```
=> #<Account id: 1, name: "ccromar", whitelisted_users: []>
```

Using `#push` or `<<` does the following:

```
2.3.3 :002 > a.whitelisted_users << 'email@mail.com'
 => ["email@mail.com"]
2.3.3 :003 > a.changed?
 => true
2.3.3 :004 > a.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Account Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE (LOWER("accounts"."launch_parameter") = LOWER('ccromar') AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE (LOWER("accounts"."launch_parameter") = LOWER('ccromar') AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE  AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "whitelisted_users" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."id" = $3  [["whitelisted_users", "---\n- email@mail.com\n"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-05 22:08:47.753699"], ["id", 1]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "whitelisted_users" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."id" = $3  [["whitelisted_users", "---\n- email@mail.com\n"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-05 22:08:47.753699"], ["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "---
- email@mail.com
"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
: UPDATE "accounts" SET "whitelisted_users" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."id" = $3
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:602:in `exec_prepared'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:602:in `block in exec_cache'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:601:in `exec_cache'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:585:in `execute_and_clear'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:173:in `exec_delete'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:114:in `update'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `update'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:88:in `_update_record'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:515:in `_update_record'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:79:in `_update_record'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:128:in `_update_record'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `block in _update_record'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
... 29 levels...
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/ccromar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

More interestingly, when I try to save more than one record to the Array, it says it commits, but the array is still empty.

```
2.3.3 :002 > a.whitelisted_users = ['email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
 => ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com"]
2.3.3 :003 > a.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Account Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true
2.3.3 :004 > a
 => #<Account id: 1, canvas_url: "https://ccromar.instructure.com", whitelisted_users: []>2.3.3 :002 > a.whitelisted_users = ['email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
 => ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com"]
2.3.3 :003 > a.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Account Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true
2.3.3 :004 > a
 => #<Account id: 1, canvas_url: "https://ccromar.instructure.com", whitelisted_users: []>2.3.3 :002 > a.whitelisted_users = ['email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
 => ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com"]
2.3.3 :003 > a.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Account Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."canvas_url" = 'https://ccromar.instructure.com' AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true
2.3.3 :004 > a
 => #<Account id: 1, canvas_url: "https://ccromar.instructure.com", name: "ccromar", whitelisted_users: []>
```

Possibly relevant details - Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 4.2.5.2, Postgres 9.5.4

Comment: Can you show how it is showing if you add multiple items in the array ?

Comment: OR simply use `add_column :things, :data, :json, default: []` It will work for sure.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli see edit

Comment: Can you show what `a.whitelisted_users.class` returns ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli it returns an Array

Comment: Try dirty tracking it can work like :
`
a.whitelisted_users_will_change!
a.whitelisted_users << 'email1@email.com'
a.whitelisted_users << 'email2@email.com'
a.save!
`

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli That returns the same malformed array literal error

Comment: Can you clarify what the :json flag in place of array: true would do?

Comment: What does the `Account` class look like? If you look at the "malformed array literal" error you'll see that someone is trying to use the YAML version of the array where PostgreSQL expects to see a PostgreSQL array, that suggests that you might have a stray `serialize` somewhere in `Account`.

Comment: @muistooshort see edit

Comment: The SQL I'm seeing doesn't match the `Account` class that you pasted in (and then removed). The `SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE (LOWER("accounts"."launch_parameter") = LOWER('ccromar') AND "accounts"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1` existence test for example doesn't match. So I'm wondering if you're actually running the `Account` class you think you are.